# Angular Date Format changing the date

Tags: angular, date, user-interface

Using Angular 4, we have a date that we're trying to show in our UI. When we fetch the date from our endpoint, it comes in as the following:

```
2018-04-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

Now, in the UI, just doing the following:

```
activeRule.startDate
```

results in the above being displayed.

However, when I try and format that date with the following:

```
{{activeRule.startDate | date : 'MMM d, y' : 'UTC' }}
```

The rule displays a day earlier as

```
Apr 2, 2018
```

I've tried appending the timezone value, but nothing's worked.
It's odd to me that the date format changes the value retrieved. Can someone offer insight and assistance? Thanks.

---

I solved this issue using the moment framework.

```
rule.startDate = moment(rule.startDate, 'YYYYMMDD').toISOString()
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, Angular's date pipe will display the date and time in your browser's local time zone. For example, if you're located in the Eastern time zone in the United States, `2018-04-03T00:00:00.000Z` is equal to `Mon Apr 02 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EDT)`. In Angular 5 you can override this behavior by passing in a timezone:

```
{{activeRule.startDate | date : 'MMM d, y' : '+0000'}}
```

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: This doesn't appear to have the desired effect. It still displays a day early. Is this exclusively an Angular 5 thing?

Comment: Could be. The internationalization of the pipes was changed in 5. You can read more about it here: https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-angular5/

Comment: @RunFranks525 works fine with Angular 5.0.0: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwvhcx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. Why don't you post a complete example reproducing the issue?

Comment: @JBNizet Our Application is an Angular 4 app and it seems that pipe's changes were part of the Angular 5 upgrade so we can't leverage it. That being said, i went ahead with the moment framework and found a nice fix. will update accordingly.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were using Angular 5. Why don't you upgrade? The upgrade is easy, and you'll have to do it eventually anyway.